# Gmail API for objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, api, gmail

To my understanding to read emails from an iphone app I can use IMAP and OAuth, for sending there's SMTP. But what if I want my app to access GMail tags or other features gmail has to offer. Is that possible? What other apps like MailBox are using? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google provides IMAP extensions for doing exactly what you want. You will have to create your own Objective-C wrapper/parser to use these extensions, though.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions